# how to load a component after useEffect is rendered

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am using the npm package `react-form-builder2`.

```
const [stateform, setstateform] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get(
          `${server}/api/getservice/6`,
          { headers }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.data[0].intakeForm) {
            setstateform(JSON.parse(response.data[0].intakeForm));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }, []);

console.log("stateform", stateform); // [{id: "0DA5756A-BDF4-4D57-97CD-5F173361C29E", element: "Label", text: "Label", static: true, required: false}]

<ReactFormBuilder
    data={stateform}
    onPost={(e) => change(e)}
/>
```

But the `data` inside `ReactFormBuilder` is not rendered as the useEffect was not loaded initially. How do i reload the `ReactFormBuilder` after the useEffect is rendered?

Comment: what does `response.data[0].intakeForm` give? array or something else ?

Comment: same as stateform - [{id: "0DA5756A-BDF4-4D57-97CD-5F173361C29E", element: "Label", text: "Label", static: true, required: false}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
const [stateform, setstateform] = useState([]);
const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState('not_loaded'); // not_loaded | loading | loaded | error

useEffect(() => {
      setLoadingState('loading')
      axios
        .get(
          `${server}/api/getservice/6`,
          { headers }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          setLoadingState('loaded');
          if (response.data[0].intakeForm) {
            setstateform(JSON.parse(response.data[0].intakeForm));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setLoadingState('error');
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }, []);

{loadingState === 'not_loaded' && 'whatever you want to be here'}
{loadingState === 'loading' && 'loading'}
{loadingState === 'error' && 'something went wrong'}
{loadingState === 'loaded' && (
  <ReactFormBuilder
    data={stateform}
    onPost={(e) => change(e)}
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stateform` to render conditionally.

```js
...
return (
  { stateform.length
    ? <ReactFormBuilder
        data={stateform}
        onPost={(e) => change(e)}
      />
    : 'loading...'
  }
);
...
```

Comment: It worked but some cases stateform.length value is empty, i want the form to be show that time too.